# How to use string array field in Kafka ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

After creating `users` stream with its `interests` field as a string array `ARRAY<STRING>` data type:

```
CREATE STREAM users
  (userid VARCHAR,
   interests ARRAY<STRING>)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'users',
        VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

I go ahead and insert the first user data with:

```
INSERT INTO users (userid, interests) VALUES ('user0001', ['music','sport'])
```

Unfortunately this insert statement fails with an error

```
line 1:60: extraneous input '[' expecting {'(', 'STRING'...
```

I tried to replace the square bracket `[]` with `()` as:

```
INSERT INTO users (userid, interests) VALUES ('user0001', ('music','sport'))
```

but it fails too.

How to fix this error? Is there a way to store a sting array `['music','sport']` using string array data type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `ARRAY` function:

https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#array

```
INSERT INTO users (userid, interests) VALUES ('user0001', ARRAY['music','sport']);
```